# Send Error Message From Sql Server to Email

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, stored-procedures

I have SP in SQL Server Agent. for better knowledge lets read this example

```
USE msdb
EXEC sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name = 'MyProfile',
  @recipients = 'Someone@something.com',
  @subject = 'T-SQL Query Result',
  @body = 'The result from SELECT is appended below.',
  @execute_query_database = 'msdb',  
  @query = 'SELECT *FROM [DB_Mh].[dbo].[mMhs]',
```

The result is, sql sent me an email like this.

> The result from SELECT is appended below.
>
> ```
> nim                  fullname              
> ----------------    ---------- 
> 443141100778          Betty 
> 4431411006571         Jessica    
> 4431411002372         Dian
> ```

and if an error happen, sql didn't send me any email. so with that script above sql only sent me the result of sql and didn't send me any notification if there is something wrong happen. what I want to ask is How to make sql send me email notification if an error happen with it error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@append_query_error` parameter.

> Specifies whether to send the e-mail when an error returns from the
>   query specified in the @query argument.

More @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190307.aspx